# Noun clause (singular all the time?)

Tags: grammar, verb-agreement, noun-phrases

I have asked one grammarian about this and she ended up being unsure of her answer.
Question: is there a possibility that a noun clause is used in a plural manner? For instance:
- Her eyes and nose are WHAT SCARE ME.
- WHAT SCARE ME are her eyes and nose.

Should the word "scare" be "scares" in the examples?
Should "are" be "is" then?

Comment: For plural I would prefer *Those which scare me are ....*  Because "what" is inherently singular.

Comment: [It's hard to tell whether I've accepted an answer](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11806/its-hard-to-tell-whether-ive-accepted-an-answer) to see what an accepted answer should look like. Here is the relevant link explaining what [an accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/223820) is

Answer (score 5):

Interesting question :)

I'd say this is an example of a fused relative (see e.g. [CaGEL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521431468)* p 1073); that is, *what scares me* is not a clause at all, but a noun phrase, where *what* is a fusion between the head function and the relativised element of a postmodifying relative clause. In this case it could be paraphrased either as *that which scares me* where *that* is the head, and *which* is the relativised subject of the postmodifying relative clause *which scares me*, or as *the things which scare me*, where the determiner *the*, the head *things* and the relativised subject of the postmodifying relative clause *which scare me* have fused.

In answer to your question, then, it could be *what scare me **are** her eyes and nose* as well as *what scare**s** me **is** her eyes and nose*.

Comment: Yeah, it's short for _the thing that scares me_, or in this case, it could just as easily be _the things that scare me_. Since this is a commutable verb phrase, _Her eyes and nose are what scare(s) me_ is just as good. And either singular or plural will do for _scare(s)_, since _what_ can mark either number. It depends, in other words, on what you mean.

Comment: @JohnLawler Thank you – that's what I was uncertain about. I'll edit my answer to make it clearer :)

Comment: Well said, Hannah. +1

Comment: @BillJ Thank you. Means a lot coming from you :)

Answer (score -1):

It's right as you had it: 'scare' and 'are'. 'Eyes and nose' are three things and require plural verbs. 'what' doesn't have separate singular and plural forms.

Comment: The first part of the first example is correct, yes, but not the rest, right? Is that what you mean? Also, I'm curious about your last sentence there – "'what' doesn't have separate singular and plural forms" – what do you mean by that? Would it be possible to clarify?

Comment: (a) "Her eyes and nose are WHAT SCARE ME." - "WHAT SCARE ME are her eyes and nose." Both are right. (b) 'What' is always 'what'; it doesn't change form according to whether one object or more than one object is being referred to.

Comment: Ah, right, now I see what you meant by that last sentence, and of course you're right about that – that it doesn't change its form, I mean. It's always singular. :) I disagree with the rest though – surely it should be *Her eyes and nose are what scares me* and *What scares me is her eyes and nose* respectively?

Comment: "surely it should be Her eyes and nose are what scares me and What scares me is her eyes and nose respectively?" Verbs change their form according to whether the subject of the sentence or clause is singular or plural. "scares' and "is" are third person SINGULAR forms, but the subject is plural (two eyes plus one nose!).

Comment: Yes, of course, but in the cases I'm marking *her eyes and nose* is not the subject – *what* is, and since *what* is singular, so should the verb be. See what I mean?

Comment: 'what' ISN'T singular:  'what' can refer to either singular or plural.In your sentence you can replace "what" by "the things that". I'd like to apologise for an unintentionally patronising tone, by the way.

Comment: Oh, I don't detect a patronising tone! I see now what you mean, and I just had it confirmed from John Lawler in his comment to my answer as well :) That was what I was uncertain about to begin with – whether *what* could be treated as plural as well, because as far as I knew, it's only treated as singular – that's why I asked you to clarify :) Now I've learnt something new – thank you :)

Comment: @Hannah- 'what' asks a question, and does not presume to know the quantity beforehand.  Although the answer may be singular or plural, we can see by the *agreement* that it is usually used in a singular way, and we do not ask questions like "*what are in the fridge", "*what fall from the sky", "*what are on TV tonight", even when we expect a plural answer.

Comment: @AmI Thanks! This may well have been what confused me – you're right :) The fact that **interrogative** *what* is singular, I mean.

Comment: Hi, guys. Sorry for the late response. Thanks for all the answers, but don't you think "what" should be followed by "scare" when we have known for sure that there are more than one entity serving as the subject/object of the sentence?